# Creating JSON-RPC PHP client/server setup: permissions question

Tags: users

I am currently creating two modules in two sites, a client and a server on each site respectively.  I want the client to be able to be called from code in any module that needs to communicate with the other site.  Each site has at least ten custom roles.  Is there a way to grant a global permission, I.E. All, or do I need to grant it to every role explicitly?

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but couldn't you just tick "Anonymous" and "Authenticated" roles? That would cover everybody

Comment: I'll be programmatically assigning roles in the .module file.  No user will directly access these modules at all, they are purely for syncing data.  Which is why I am fuzzy on permissions required.